# How does Laravel transform Models and Collections with json_decode?

Tags: php, laravel

I am just now getting my feet wet with Laravel. I found out that while debugging a Laravel class (be it a Model, Collection etc) with xdebug, its not usually very helpful to see the class structure, you can get good data by passing it through json_decode. This cuts out all the extra data and presents the relevant data in a clean object.

I wanted to know how Laravel does this under the scene. I understand the idea of Facades and how that takes advantage of PHP's magic functions when calling a function not on the object. But, would that somehow make you json_decode something which is not json?

Example:

```
/* @var \Rainlab\User\Models\User */
$user = Auth::getUser();
// $user_json ends up as an object of user data.
$user_json = json_decode($user);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a model through `json_decode` and not `json_encode` ?

Comment: Yes, I"m positive, see my example I added.

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly: functions are not part of the json resulting from encoding.

Comment: @Thomas - see my accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism is the magic function `__toString` which for a `Model` is:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->toJson();
}
```

`toJson` roughly does a `json_encode($this)` (with some error checks).

The way the extra members are stripped out is because `Model` implements [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) which alters the behaviour that `json_encode` has on that object.

So the whole process for `json_decode($model)` is:

1. Since `json_decode` is an internal PHP function then [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) will occur which will try to coerce the `$model` into a string
2. Part of coercing an object to a string is to look for the magic `__toString` method and calling that if it exists
3. `__toString` will call `toJson`
4. `toJson` generates a valid JSON string which for models only includes their attributes. The implementation of the `jsonSerialize` function can be seen [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1111) and following it around shows why it behaves the way it does
5. `json_decode` on a valid json string will result in an object (or array) based on the JSON string provided, in this case the model attributes only

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel implements [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php), a built-in PHP interface that lets a class define how it gets rendered down to JSON.

Under the hood, it's [passing the object through `toArray`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1111).

Comment: As per @apokryfos above, really the full path is __toString -> toJson -> jsonSerialize -> toArray. But thanks for the link to the code.